# Express-Validation, request to server error 500

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

when i move code (this between //   //) into function i write in code(here):

```
   router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {

  var login = req.body.login;
  var password = req.body.password;

  console.log(req.body)

  req.checkBody('login', 'Login is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    console.log('yes')
  } else {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//here
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        newUser.password = hash;
        var user = new User(newUser);
        user.save()
          .then(function (User) {
            res.send(User);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })

          ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
    });
  }
});
```

He can't insert data to database, because is 500 Internal Server Error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?? I can't insert options with insert data to database into another function or what??

Comment: Can you paste the exact error ?

Comment: Stack trace can help a lot, add it, please.

Comment: You're probably getting a silent error before you get to the response. do you see any errors in the server's logs?

Comment: Ah my false, I got mistake in app.use in function with express validator, I have question how can I print errors in EJS template if i made:   if (errors) {
    console.log(errors)
    res.render('index', {
      errors: errors
    });    because if i write in code in index <%= errors %> on site I am directed to  ERROR File not Found